# Making a get request to a Discord text file to get the file contents

Tags: python, request, python-requests, discord.py

I am trying to get the contents of a text file through get requests however I am receiving a strange response with Greek letters and spaces between each character.

Link:

```
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/651144916944027658/717426226255495208/my_file.txt
```

Headers:

```
Content-Type: text/plain
```

My text file contents:

```
123.456.789
```

Response after doing the get request:

```
ÿþ1 2 3 . 4 5 6 . 7 8 9
```

I'm not sure if there are some headers that I am missing but I can't seem to get this to work, I've tried in C# and Python and have received the same response each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file is being attached to a message, you'll be able to `save()` it:

```py
@bot.command()
async def savefile(ctx):
    await ctx.message.attachments[0].save("my_file.txt")
    await ctx.send("Saved the file!")
```

You can also add checks for certain file extensions and such.
If you want to save it with the same file name it was uploaded with:

```py
@bot.command()
async def savefile(ctx):
    attachment = ctx.message.attachments[0]
    # this will save it with the correct file extension
    await attachment.save(attachment.filename) 
    await ctx.send("Saved the file!")
```

---

**References:**

- [`Message.attachments`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.attachments)
- [`Attachment.save()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Attachment.save)